Help identifying this wind instrument
I was listening a traditional song "Oy u gayu pry Dunaju" (Oh, in the grove by the Danube) performed by a ukrainian band "Hurt Express" and I have noticed right from the beginning an instrument, likely a wind instrument, which somewhat resembles a flute. This instrument approximately repeats the voice melody, partially, when the singer is mute. In some places (at the seconds 4-5; 1:51-1:52 or 2:53) it also makes an interesting sound similar to the guitar slide up (a glissando, I guess).
Could you identify this instrument? I thought that is could be a saxophone.

Welcome. If you read the help centre, you'll understand why this sort of question gets closed. Sorry!

Sorry, but questions asking to identify instruments etc. like this are off-topic, see What topics can I ask about here?. However, you can ask in one of chat rooms: The Practice Room, and you might get an answer there.

@Tim, no problem, I understand

@Elements, great! I could try that
